# Fundamental question - Chat app using socket.io, Node JS, Express and Mongo

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I'm new to development in general, so if the answer question seems very strightforward or if some of the terminology seems incorrect, then please allow some leeway. Also, I've spent the last few days trying to understand this, so, my part of due diligence has been done as well.

**Goal:** 
Implement a chat application. After a user is authenticated, he / she is redirected to a room (unique to him), with a list of all the users in the DB.
Stack : Socket.io, Node JS, Express, EJS and Mongo DB

I've implemented an API which will check if the user exists in the DB and redirect successful users.

I believe I have an understanding of socket.io mechanics i.e. events can emitted and are consumed by either the server or the client.

**The trouble I have is understanding how to tie the 2 (passing data from Express/EJS to socket.io) together**

What I would like to have -
1. POST route will authenticate the user and redirect to the /chat GET route
(For now, I'm not using real authentication)

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  db.User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, (err, user) => {
    if (!user) {
      res.send("user not found");
    } else if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.redirect("/chat");
    }
  });
});
```

2. This /chat GET route renders the page index.ejs

   app.get("/chat", (req, res) => res.render("index"));

3.In the index.ejs, I would like to have the user information of the authenticated user, all the users in the DB. This, I believe would comes from the post route. I'm aware how to pass the data from Express to an EJS template, but not when socket.io is involved.

Socket.io code

```
ChatNsp.on("connection", client => {
  console.log(`Client ${client.id} connected`);
  client.emit("my event", { custom: "data" });

  client.on("disconnect", () =>
    console.log("Client " + client.id + " disconnected")
  );
});
Any pointers would be appreciated. I've been trying to figure this out for the last few days.
```

Client code

```
const socket = io.connect("/chat");

socket.on("connect", function() {
  alert("Connected to the server");

  socket.on("my event", data => console.log(data));
});
```

Comment: In the POST route establish a session (see [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)).   Then, on subsequent http calls or upon a socket.io connection, on your server you can get access to that session object to find out who the authenticated user is and any other information about them you put in the session object.  Any of this data you want the client-side to know, you will have to either have the client ask for with an Ajax call (and the server can auth them from the session) or you will have to embed that data in the page with EJS when its rendered.

Comment: Thanks ! I'm not familiar with express-session, but will give it a try.